# How to make bar rating system like flipkart app in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement the bar trying system in iOS. Someone please suggest some ideas or third parties for bar rating based on the number of users like Flipkart, Amazon apps?

[image]

Comment: :- What do you mean by bar trying system??..

Comment: check the edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HCSStarRatingView for displaying star rating and UIProgressView for displaying bars

```
UIProgressView * progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
progressView.progress = .50;
progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Comment: Thanks Coder. Your post is helpful.